# parse error on input `='?

Tags: haskell, syntax, compiler-errors, keyword

I am a newbie to Haskell and am trying to cipher the plain text by using shifting the ASCII values and if my plain text contains a number,then it has to encode each digit by putting a special symbol in place of the digit like (0=*,1='\',2=~,3=!,4=@,5=#,6=$, 7=%,8=^,9=&).here below is my code

```
import Data.Char

isInRange :: Char -> Char -> Char -> Bool
isInRange l u c = (c >= l) && (c <= u)

--is this Letter to be ciphered
canEncrypt :: Char -> Bool
canEncrypt c = isLower(c) && isAscii(c)

-should we wrap around the alphabet ?
wraparound shift c
 | isLower c && ord(c)+shift > ord 'z' = True
 | otherwise = False

--encrypt single char at a time
encryptChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
encryptChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
encryptChar shift c
  | canEncrypt c = chr (ord c + wrapshift)
  | isUpper c = c
  Where wrapshift = let shift' = ord(shift) `mod` 26
                    in if (wraparound shift' c)
                        then shift'-26
                        else shift'
encryptChar _ '0' = '*'
encryptChar _ '1' = '\''
encryptChar _ '2' = '~'
encryptChar _ '3' = '!'
encryptChar _ '4' = '@'
encryptChar _ '5' = '#'
encryptChar _ '6' = '$'
encryptChar _ '7' = '%'
encryptChar _ '8' = '^'
encryptChar _ '9' = '&'
encryptChar _ c = c

encryptText :: String -> String -> String
encryptText text xs = [ encryptChar x s | x <- xs, s <- text]
```

so far so good, to wraparound my ciphered characters I have defined `wrapshift` function(i think its the culprit)  but when I compile it, it showing an error like below

```
encrypt2.hs:27:18: error:
parse error on input `='
Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
   |
27 |  Where wrapshift = let shift' = ord(shift) `mod` 26
   |                  ^
Failed, 0 modules loaded.
```

I know these kinds of error occurs due to `tabs` in my source file but I have checked the total file and didn't find any mistake.I think am doing something wrong here I don't know what ? why is this error occurring please help me I have been struck here .thank you

Comment: `Where wrapshift` should be `where wrapshift` -- case matters.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. By accepting a answer you are indicating to future readers that it is a correct answer.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#where

Answer (score 5):

```
Where wrapshift
```

Note how the `where` here is not highlighted as a keyword. That's because you spelled it with a capital "W".

So it's interpreted as an identifier instead of a keyword, making `Where wrapshift` be interpreted as arguments to the previous expression (i.e. `c Where wrapshift` is seen as a function call). That's why it does not expect a `=` there.